# Read Kudu from SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, jdbc, kudu

In Spark I am unable to find how to connect to Kudu using SparkR. If I try the following in scala:

```
import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
import org.apache.kudu.client._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// Read kudu table and select data of August 2018
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.options(Map("kudu.master" -> "198.y.x.xyz:7051","kudu.table" -> "table_name")).kudu
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
```

it works perfectly. In SparkR I have been trying to the following:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sc = sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"), sparkPackages = "org.apache.kudu:kudu-spark2_2.11:1.8.0")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df = read.jdbc(url="198.y.x.xyz:7051",
               driver = "jdbc:kudu:sparkdb",
               source="jdbc",
               tableName = "table_name" 
               )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in jdbc : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdbc:kudu:sparkdb
```

Trying the following:

```r
df = read.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://198.19.10.103:7051",
               tableName = "banglalink_data_table_1" 
               )
```

gives:

```
Error: Error in jdbc : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

I cannot find any help on how to load the correct driver. I think that using the sparkPackages option is correct as it gives no error. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: The `driver` entry expects the JDBC driver classname, not a JDBC url.

Comment: What would be the correct class name for a kudu database

Comment: I have no idea. Look at the documentation of the JDBC driver for kudu.